# Compare $(fg)''$ and $(fg)'''$ with expansion of $(a+b)^2$ and $(a+b)^3$

Tags: calculus

I have already expanded out all 4 and although I can see relation between $(fg)''$ and $(a+b)^2$. I cannot see any for $(fg)'''$ and $(a+b)^3$. Am I missing something here.? 
$(fg)''=f''g+2f'g'+f'g''$

$(a+b)^2$=$a^2+2ab+b^2$

$(fg)'''=f'''g+3f''g'+2f'g''+f''g''+f'g'''$

$(a+b)^3=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3$

Comment: Can you edit (in you question) your expansions - at least for $(fg)''$ and $(a+b)^2?$

Comment: Ok it seems like I just calculated (fg)''' wrong

Comment: Now that you have done the expansions what similarity do you notice? That should answer your "compare" question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(fg)' = f'g + fg' $$

$$(fg)''= (f'g+fg')' = f''g + f'g' +f'g' + fg'' = f''g + 2f'g' +fg''$$

$$ (fg)''' = (f''g + 2f'g' +fg'')' = f'''g +f''g' +2f''g' + 2 f'g'' +f'g''+fg''' $$

$$= f'''g + 3f''g' +3f'g''+ fg'''$$